# i want insert a userid in another table , there is primary key uid in users table and its foreign key in cardtable

Tags: postgresql

```
 Create OR REPLACE PROCEDURE adduser(
        fname varchar , lname varchar , pass varchar , uname varchar ,
            cnumber integer, cname varchar
            
        )
        language SQL
        BEGIN ATOMIC 
        insert into users(firstname , lastname , password , username ) Values (fname , lname , pass , uname);
         select * from users AS uids;
        insert into users_card (cardnumber , cardname , userid) values (cnumber , cname , uids);
        END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to firstly insert data into user table, after then get `userid(uuid)` of inserted data and insert this to another table.

Sample:

```
 do
 $body$
 declare
    vuserid uuid;
 begin
    
    insert into users (first_name, last_name)
    values ('Jon', 'Smith')
    returning uids into vuserid; 

    insert into users_card(card_number, card_name, userid)
    values (123, 'test', vuserid);

 end;
 $body$
 language 'plpgsql';
```